# Fancy Sliding form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am using the code from [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/) and it is working fine, but when I remove the paragraphs

and add a table with inputs and without <"p">, i face the issue.
the issue is as below:
when you are moving out from the last input in the slide using TAB button to move to the next selected input text in the next slide, the next slide will be unorgnized !

here is an example for the code **without issue**:

```
<fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Account</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="username">User name</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="info@tympanus.net"
        type="email" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF
        />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

here is an example for the code **with issue**:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="username">User name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="info@tympanus.net"
            tabindex="2" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" tabindex="3" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

without adding the last line, the code will work, but the TAB will not, it will jump to the next slide directly without selecting the inputs in the same slide.

how can i fix this issue by moving between the tabbed form, with TAB button without any issue.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net example? I'd guess it's one of two things: 1. Tables not having the same display type as a <p>
2. The javascript might be trying to select a specific item that you've changed to something else.

Comment: I added it into jsfiddle.net http://jsfiddle.net/amigo_sa/rqWB8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
It was in the .js file, to replce this line

```
$fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){
```

with this line

```
$fieldset.children(':last').find(':last:input').keydown(function(e)
```

because it was going to the last child but not the last input.

Answer (score 0):

I only briefly looked at the codrops website but it seems to me that you are missing the `<fieldset class="step"> ... </fieldset>` tags that each set of input fields must be wrapped in. Try and put your table(s) - I guess there must be more than one, otherwise why would you be using fancysliding? - inside these tags.

Comment: i forgot to add it in the code example, but it is not the issue.